# No links working in umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, hyperlink, umbraco

the links are suddenly not working on our umbraco project. All links (umbraco links that is, like @Model.Url, not hard coded links) are not working, and just points to "localhost:8080".

I got a error, complaining about null-pointer exception at this code:

```
namespace Sk.Web.Routing
{
    public class ExternalUrlProvider : IUrlProvider
    {
        public string GetUrl(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, int id, Uri current, UrlProviderMode mode)
        {
            var node = umbracoContext.ContentCache.GetById(id);
            return node.HasValue("umbracoExternalUrl")
                ? node.GetPropertyValue<string>("umbracoExternalUrl")
                : "";
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> GetOtherUrls(UmbracoContext umbracoContext, int id, Uri current)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

When selecting nodes in the backoffice.

Also, when i debugged, i noticed the page-model missed the "umbracoExternalUrl" field. Weird.

Someone have any idea of what is going on here?

Comment: What version of Umbraco?
Also, can you point the entire contents of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two issues you are reporting here:

- Links that just point to /
- A null reference exception in your back office

Also, you should really quote the source of the code you are using (which is http://www.theoutfield.net/blog/2013/10/handling-external-urls-in-umbraco-6)

To clarify, the code is *overriding* what URL is returned by Umbraco when you call `@Model.Url` by using the one specified in the `umbracoExternalUrl` field.

If you read further into the article, you will see that you need to create an `ApplicationEventHandler`:

```
public class Bootstrapper : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationInitialized(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    { }

    public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        UrlProviderResolver.Current.InsertTypeBefore<DefaultUrlProvider, ExternalUrlProvider>();
    }

    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    { }
}
```

Check that this hasn't been changed or removed.

If all your published site page links are displaying / then this means the code above is hitting the line `node.HasValue("umbracoExternalUrl")` and returning false. Therefore, you need to republish your site to update the XML and content cache.

If you are getting a null reference exception in the back office, it is almost certainly because there is no `UmbracoContext`. You need to provide more information in order for this to be answered, i.e. what action exactly in the back-office is causing the exception to occur. For example, is it a bespoke section or a multi-node picker?

If it is a custom section or datatype, you need to make sure the `UmbracoContext` is available to the code at runtime.

*Note:* Thanks to http://www.theoutfield.net/ for the code.